# Run a specific page on both the servers that are load balanced

Tags: load-balancing, iis-8

I have 2 Web servers(IIS) which are load balanced.

When a refresh cache(http://<>/recache.asmx page) is run on one of the sever which the load balancer points, it should also be run on the another server.

Can any one please suggest the IIS rules that can be used?